# Is there a way to add image alt tags to all the images?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, seo, thumbnail

I'm looking to add alt tags to all the images on a Magento website, is there a way to do this without going through each individual product and i want to include the alt tag in the thumbnails as well.

Comment: Does solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Luke,welcome MSE.

In magento default theme ***, alt tag are added to every images*** where images are called.It is an standard code work of magento.

For custom **module/theme** *Magento does not responsible for* **alt tag**.it is **skip of those themes and modules**

Maybe you use ***any custom theme and  custom module*** where they don't put the **alt** to image tag ,so you need to **some custom code on that theme or custom modules** in order to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can get product name  or any other attribute text in alt and title. If you do not want to go to every product, you can import image labels via excel which are by default title for product images